# hive not showing the query output

Tags: hadoop, hive

Query: `select ename from emp1 where empno='21';`

```
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1505887467311_0011, Tracking URL = http://ubuntu:8088/proxy/application_1505887467311_0011/
Kill Command = /home/ramya/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.2/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1505887467311_0011
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2017-09-20 03:05:16,123 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2017-09-20 03:05:30,109 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 2.05 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 2 seconds 50 msec
Ended Job = job_1505887467311_0011
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 2.05 sec   HDFS Read: 255 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 2 seconds 50 msec
OK
Time taken: 62.139 seconds
hive> select ename from emp1 where empno like'%21%';
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_1505887467311_0012, Tracking URL = http://ubuntu:8088/proxy/application_1505887467311_0012/
Kill Command = /home/ramya/hadoop-2.5.0-cdh5.3.2/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1505887467311_0012
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2017-09-20 03:09:11,164 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2017-09-20 03:09:21,952 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 0%, Cumulative CPU 1.62 sec
MapReduce Total cumulative CPU time: 1 seconds 620 msec
Ended Job = job_1505887467311_0012
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 1.62 sec   HDFS Read: 255 HDFS Write: 0 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 1 seconds 620 msec
OK
Time taken: 32.903 seconds
```

Its not displaying the output. Where we have to see the output?

Comment: how do you run this query? From command line or from web browser? Maybe emp1 table is empty... :)

Comment: from command line.table is not empty.it is showing select * from emp1;This query was executed and got output.

Comment: Probably there are no records with empno='21' ???